# Thymeleaf page source not properly formatted

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I am using `layout:fragment` to embed some HTML. When I right click and view the page source I noticed that the format of the HTML is not properly formatted. For instance, a div tag will be out of place (which will cause the content within it to be misaligned). Similarly, there seems to be white-space in certain parts of the web page. I have used a HTML formatter so the thymeleaf in my webpage is formatted properly.

I believe the project is called layout-dialect. The GitHub url is here: https://github.com/ultraq/thymeleaf-layout-dialect

Does anyone know a way to prevent this from happening?

The home page of the application has the following:

```
 <div class="container">
     <div layout:fragment="content">
     </div>
 </div>
```

The page that it is linking to is this:

```
<div layout:fragment="content">
  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/posts/new">Add new post</a>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/posts/report">View post report</
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show your code and the output?

Comment: I use thymeleaf and I have never experimented that problem. If you show (briefly) your code I can test it.

Comment: @Troncador I've tried to add the necessary code. Please let me know if this is enough for you to test

Comment: @Albert Where did you right click and see? IDE or a web browser? Is it the code formatting problem or the html rendering problem? Could you add a screenshot maybe for us to understand it clearly?

Comment: My answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in your code. It should be layout:replace instead of layout:fragment

```
<div class="container">
  <div layout:fragment="content">
```

My version of your code:

Main.java

```
public static void main(String arg[]){
  FileTemplateResolver templateResolver = new FileTemplateResolver();
  // path to the files *.html
  templateResolver.setPrefix("/home/user/desktop/"); 
  templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
  templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
  TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
  templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);

  Context ctx = new Context();
  String text = templateEngine.process("index", ctx);

  // print html processed
  System.out.println(text);
}
```

Dependency in maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring3</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<body>
    <h1>Index</h1>
    <div th:replace="content :: fooName"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

content.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
  <body>
    <div th:fragment="fooName">
     <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/posts/new">Add new post</a>
     <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/posts/report">View post report</a>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

And the output was:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
    <h1>Index</h1>
    <div>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/posts/new">Add new post</a>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/posts/report">View post report</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Every work fine